# Unable to get property 'client' of undefined in SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm getting the error Unable to get property 'client' of undefined while accessing the hub method clientside. 
My code is as below:

```
 I have my hub like this:
    [HubName("command")]
    public class CommandHub : Hub
    {
        public void TrackStatusCommand(string serialNumber)
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, serialNumber);
        }
        public void StatusCompleted(string serialNumber, bool status)
        {
            Clients.Group(serialNumber).statusCompleted(serialNumber, status);
        }
    }

    var hubProxy = $.connection.command, intervalHandle, timeout;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var priority = 0;
    var accNumber = $("#spnAccountNumber").data("templatepath");
    var model = $('#Model').text();
    hubProxy.client.statusCompleted = function (serialNumber, status) {
        $("#StatusData").css("display", "block");
        $('#StatusButton').prop('disabled', false);
        $.connection.hub.stop();
    };
    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {
        if ($.connection.hub.transport.name === "longPolling") {
            intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
                statusCompleted(accNumber, model, priority, status);
            }, 30000);
        }
        hubProxy.server.trackStatusCommand(serialNumber);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $.connection.hub.stop();
            $("#StatusData").css("display", "block");
        }, 60000);
    }).fail(function () {
        $('#StatusButton').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
```

Once after deleting the temporary files from the root folder in the following path I'm not getting the error and it is working as expected.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please see if this helps http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2013/02/17/asp.net-signalr-ldquoscript5007-unable-to-get-property-client-of-undefined.aspx

Comment: RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); this method has become obsolete in global.asax.cs. This has been included in Startup.cs. This is not helping anyways.

Comment: Pawel, I have updated the code. Please check.