# chat.client in undefined in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have followed this [SignalR Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

But I am getting `chat.client` is undefined.

This is my ChatHub.cs code.

```
  [HubName("ChatHub")] 
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

and my startupclass.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();

        }
    }
}
```

and in my chat view

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.ChatHub;
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            $('#message').focus();
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

I found similar question on stackoverflow, but unable to solve my problem.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268351/unable-to-get-property-client-of-undefined-in-signalr)

I have deleted temporary files from the root folder in the following path. but this didn't solve my problem.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Comment: Did it you get it working? I have a similar problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033479/signalr-2-2-0-mvc-4-error-client-undefined

Comment: @Novice: yes. 
use this [Js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.1.0.min.js)

Comment: var chat = $.connection.ChatHub; should be  var chat = $.connection.chatHub; first letter of class must be small

Answer (score 0):

I would start from checking if scripts

```
~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js
```

and

```
~/signalr/hubs
```

are available

Comment: Yes . In console I'm getting both. and I have included Js file in mylayout view

Comment: What do you mean by "I have included Js file in mylayout view" ? What Js file? I guess JQuery because all other needed Js files are already included in your chat view (section)...

Comment: @MichalLevý: Yes . you are right. I was talking about Jquery.js

Comment: As `client` is property of hub client side proxy i'm interested what is exact content of dynamically generated proxy file. Just access `<server IP and port>/signalr/hubs` in browser and paste the content into question pls...

Answer (score 0):

If your method in server side

Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);

you must write in browser side

```
chat.client.AddNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };
```

method in server side addNewMessageToPage you must write AddNewMessageToPage (big A) in browser side.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else copying the code from the tutorial and encountering the same error, you may need to change the following:

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```