# SignalR 2.2.0 MVC 4 error client undefined

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

It's almost 12 hrs no success, I have tried this code in Web Project and it worked but when integrating with my MVC application it is giving me errors

```
GET http://localhost:50843/signalr/Hubs 

DashBoard:553 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined(anonymous function) @ DashBoard:553
```

This error occurs usually when the hub script is not found I have tried many fixes but no luck here is my  code.

Project structure

[image]

References

[image]

ChatHub.cs
(I have omitted the method implementation)

```
 using System;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using SignalRTest;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Security;
    
    namespace SignalRChat
        
    {
        public class ChatHub : Hub
        {
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

[image]

This is the problem area not able to invoke the client object.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working? Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the client code you should include both `jquery.min.js`, as well as `jquery.signalR.min.js` (From what I see in your `cshtml` you are only including `jquery.signalR`).

Try including both and see if it works!

Best of luck!

EDIT: You should put your entire client code inside `$(function(){ });`
Example from the official documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {

                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

            $('#message').focus();

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {

                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Notice how the client code is wrapped inside a jQuery function.

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply but if you could see on my cshtml page I have included a reference to 

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
This automatically brings JQuery for me current version of JQuery I have is 1.9.1

Comment: Try including manually this reference and see if it works. The error that you get seems to be because of a missing reference

Comment: The order in which you reference the scripts is also very important.

Comment: Tried including manually but no luck :( , the order of the script is same as  I have shared.

Comment: Try creating a simple html file without any Razor, include the scripts by hand and see if it works.

Comment: That is exactly what I did after your previous comment but it's no working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87109/discussion-between-novice-and-matei-radu).

Answer (score 0):

I actually applied a break point at Startup.cs file to see if it is invokin gthe method `MapSignalR()` as this is the method which is responsible for invoking the hub script dynamically. And to my surprise this method is not getting invoked.

So after some more efforts I realized I was missing these references `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security` that are responsible to invoke the Startup class method through Owin.